# Should I use a compound primary key here or is UNIQUE(fk1, fk2) a better design?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am not very experienced with SQL and therefore I have troubles when it comes to decision making from time to time. What I am having are the tables `shop`, `language` and `shop_supported_language`.

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
    -- PRIMARY KEY  
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE language (
    -- PRIMARY KEY  
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    -- ATTRIBUTES   
    code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (code)   
);

CREATE TABLE shop_supported_language (

    -- PRIMARY KEY  
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    -- FOREIGN KEYS

    shop_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_supported_language__shop
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_id)
        REFERENCES shop(id),

    language_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_supported_language__language
        FOREIGN KEY (language_id)
        REFERENCES language(id) 

    -- Would definitely not hurt:
    -- UNIQUE(shop_id, language_id)
);
```

As the name suggests, `shop_supported_language` represents the languages that a shop is actually supporting. A shop can decide in what translations it wants to provide e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE shop_offer_details (

    -- PRIMARY KEY  
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    -- FOREIGN KEYS 
    shop_offer_id BIGINT NOT NULL,  
    -- ...

    shop_supported_language_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_offer_details__shop_supported_language
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_supported_language_id)
        REFERENCES shop_supported_language(id),

    -- ...
);
```

Is it a good idea to **not** have a compound primary key for `shop_supported_language`? Imho it would make sense to set a `UNIQUE` constraint to `shop_id` and `language_id` and I'm good.

Since this is a core element in my database I would like to know if what I am doing is basically okay or fundamentally dangerous.

The reason why I don't want to use that compound PK is actually `shop_offer_details`. In that case I don't have to reference a compound PK. Would that be an argument against the compound PK?

Comment: This question has been asked half a dozen times on here at least. Please use the search functionality before opening a new question.

Comment: if `(shop_id, language)`, a natural key, uniquely identifies the tuple then by all means use it in instead of the surrogate key. As I understand all the tables, with the exception of `shop`, in your shown schema have natural keys so no need for surrogate.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto What about `shop_offer_details`? Wouldn't it be easier to have just a sole PK instead of a compound one?

Comment: You should have whatever keys are required to implement the business rules that should apply to your data. If that means one composite key *and* one single attribute key then you will need two constraints. If you are going to implement two key constraints then it doesn't make any difference which of those uses the PRIMARY KEY syntax and which uses UNIQUE key syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If shop table has a shop_id that uniquely identifies the shop and if language table has a language_id that uniquely identifies the language and the relationship between those 2 tables is that a shop can support many languages and a language can be supported by many shops (many to many), then it should be fine to use shop_id and language_id as the 2 keys to identify what shop support what language and what language is used by what shops.  I don't see a need to generate another key to identify the many to many relationship (shop_id and language_id).

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use that compound PK is actually `shop_offer_details`. In that case I don't have to reference a compound PK. Would that be an argument against the compound PK?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you.  So you have other tables shop offers and shop offer details?  Shop offer details has the info of each shop offers?  And you want to say what language is associated with each shop offer detail?

Comment: Almost: I want to say what *supported* language is associated with each `shop_offer_details`. Imagine the shop owner comes from France and wants to support French. But since Germany is right next to his `shop` he decides he wants to translate his offers into German as well. So what he does is setting the languages he wants to support in `shop_supported_language` for his `shop`.

Comment: A UNIQUE NOT NULL should be declared on (shop_id,language_id) because the pair is unique and neither is individually. (Neither is a key. And "2 keys to identify what shop support what language and what language is used by what shops" uses "key" in a way that doesn't make sense.)

Comment: Ok, so you kinda answer your own question in your comment in "what he does is setting the languages he wants to support in shop_supported_language."    Thus, you can go to shop_supported_languages for what languages you need to localize the offer details.   .....(too long comment)..read next one please.

Comment: If you put the language in shop_offer_details, then you are telling me that the shop can support French, German, and Italian in shop_supported_languages but for this specific shop_offer_detail, the shop only wants to show French and German and not Italian.  If that is the case, I suggest you create a table with shop_offer_details without the language_id and then create another table that stores the shop_offer_id and language_id since the language should affect the whole offer and not just the details.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be three (candidate and/or super-) key issues muddled here: PRIMARY KEY vs UNIQUE NOT NULL keys, simple vs composite keys and natural vs surrogate keys.

A PRIMARY KEY constraint is just one of whatever UNIQUE NOT NULL constraints you have that you decided to call "primary". There's no constraint difference between declaring (FK1, FK2) a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE NOT NULL key. There might be project heuristics about when to use one over the other (eg declaring a key as PRIMARY KEY when it's the one to be used as FOREIGN KEY when you have a choice or having small values as keys for performance) and the DBMS might treat it differently (eg indexing it by default). There's no role for PRIMARY KEYs in relational theory.

There is also nothing wrong per se with composite keys. There are reasons for *adding* a simple surrogate candidate key then also using it as foreign key. Some of which are re implementation and need to be shown worth-while. And some of which are for good logical design, eg when a distinguishing id must be introduced after the system starts up or to sheild from changes in what columns are available for natural keys.